# Camel hiding middleware API send JMS exchange with headers

Tags: java, spring, jms, apache-camel

Does anybody know how to follow this recommendation at [camel pojo producing][1]:

> We recommend Hiding Middleware APIs from your application code so the
>   next option might be more suitable. You can add the @Produce
>   annotation to an injection point (a field or property setter) using a
>   ProducerTemplate or using some interface you use in your business
>   logic. e.g.
>
> ```
> public interface MyListener {
>     String sayHello(String name);
> }
>
> public class MyBean {
>     @Produce(uri = "activemq:foo")
>     protected MyListener producer;
>
>     public void doSomething() {
>         // lets send a message
>         String response = producer.sayHello("James");
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Here Camel will automatically inject a smart client side proxy at the
>   @Produce annotation - an instance of the MyListener instance. When we
>   invoke methods on this interface the method call is turned into an
>   object and using the Camel Spring Remoting mechanism it is sent to the
>   endpoint - in this case the ActiveMQ endpoint to queue foo; then the
>   caller blocks for a response.

but with headers, in order to work with this line of DSL:

```
from("jms:activemq:toBeStored").recipientList(header("stores").tokenize(",")).parallelProcessing().ignoreInvalidEndpoints();
```

which I have successfully tested with the method of @EndpointInject

```
public class Foo {
  @EndpointInject(uri="activemq:foo.bar")
  ProducerTemplate producer;

  public void doSomething() {
    if (whatever) {
      producer.sendBodyAndHeader("<hello>world!</hello>", "stores","store1");
    }
  }
}
```

like as described before the recommendation.
In brief: how can I make the injected smart client side proxy send also the headers I want?
thanks